# (Angular) Why is my array not getting empty with this?

Tags: angular, for-loop

I have a messages.component.ts that looks like this:

```
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  messages: Message[] = [];
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(public messagesService: MessagesService) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.messages.length; i++) {
      if (i === 2) {
        this.messages = [];
      }
    }

    this.subscription = this.messagesService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { this.messages.push(message); });

  }
```

My MessagesService:

```
export class MessagesService {

  constructor() { }

  private subject = new Subject<Message>();

  sendMessage(type: string, message: string): void {
    this.subject.next({text: message, type });
  }

  clearMessages(): void {
    this.subject.next();
  }
```

But my for-loop doesnt get empty, after i have 2 entries in it, why?

Comment: I guess, you need to adjust your array within the callback of your subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try this:

```
this.subscription = this.messagesService.getMessage().subscribe(
  message => { 
    if (this.message.length >= 3)
      this.message= [];
    this.messages.push(message);
  }
);
```

on your example you only add a condition while constructing you component which may not even had a subscription yet.
Here you check if index is `2` (with a start from 0) which is equivalent to `array.length >= 3`. So the trick is to check for array length on each data retrieval.

now if you still want the `for-loop` it goes a little something like this

```
this.subscription = this.messagesService.getMessage().subscribe(
  message => { 
    for (let i = 0; i < this.messages.length; i++) {
      if (i === 2) {
        this.messages = [];
      }
    }
    this.messages.push(message);
  }
);
```

Comment: I have one question, which u may can answer: 
If i have already one message, that is being displayed on my UI, THEN i have a function that puts TWO messages at a time to this array, the first message is getting deleted, because the array reaches 2 entries. How could i cope that? 
Like having one message already, but handling two message that come in without "pause"

Comment: @testtest11 can you create another post for that and send me link? thanks in advance